# Failure to patch pict2e to have a fillable oval

Tags: etoolbox, picture-mode

I am trying to patch "on the fly" `pict2e.sty` so that I can have filled ovals (this comes from here: https://github.com/Rmano/circledsteps/issues/5). I tried this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e, picture}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\newif\ifcstepsfilledovals
\patchcmd{\@oval}{\pIIe@strokeGraph}{%
    \ifcstepsfilledovals\pIIe@fillGraph\else\pIIe@strokeGraph\fi
    }{\typeout{OK}}{\typeout{FAIL}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\circle*{30pt}}}
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\oval(30pt, 20pt)}}
\begingroup\cstepsfilledovalstrue
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\oval(30pt, 20pt)}}
\endgroup
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\oval(30pt, 20pt)}}

\end{document}
```

If I do the patch by hand, on a copy of the file, it works --- but `etoolbox` is saying this:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 9
[debug] analyzing '\@oval'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -- search pattern not found in replacement text
FAIL
```

And I fail to see why. I suspect a catcode thing that I don't understand...

Comment: As a cat, I could help you with the cat code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmQhF.png ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat yes, I saw it --- very nice. It reminds me of the cat in [Simak's Mastodonia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1436437.Mastodonia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading `picture`, which basically redefines every `pict2e` macro. In this case you need to patch `\PcOrg@@oval`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e, picture}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifcstepsfilledovals
\@ifpackageloaded{picture}{\patchcmd\PcOrg@@oval}{\patchcmd\@oval}
  {\pIIe@strokeGraph}
  {\ifcstepsfilledovals\pIIe@fillGraph\else\pIIe@strokeGraph\fi}
  {\typeout{OK}}{\typeout{FAIL}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\circle*{30pt}}}
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\oval(30pt, 20pt)}}
\begingroup\cstepsfilledovalstrue
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\oval(30pt, 20pt)}}
\endgroup
\makebox(30pt,30pt){\put(0,0){\oval(30pt, 20pt)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]